# Admob error in iPhone

Tags: iphone, admob

I used Admob in my application.

But it showing the error, when ad will load.

The error is : "Unable to fill ad request.  This is a common situation"

How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a a mistake, it just means that Admob doesn't have any advertisements to send you.

If this is happening in the simulator then things are fine: while testing in the simulator Admob will send you a variety of different responses, including this one, so you can make sure your code is ready to handle every possibility.

If this is happening on the device then it simply means that Admob doesn't have any ads for you right now. Ad companies have a limited supply of ads to send out, with specific rules for which apps get certain ads. The message simply says that there are no ads available for your app now.

Answer (score 1):

As your error message do not comes under the [error response as suggested by Admob](http://developer.admob.com/wiki/API_Responses) it is just a temporary problem which is corrected automatically after some time.

You do not need to change anything in your code.

For any other problem in iAD integration [follow this guide](http://developer.admob.com/wiki/IPhone)